# How to export Docker-machine configuration to be used on other machines

Tags: docker, docker-machine

What's the best way to move docker-machine machines (remote not local host) from one computer to another (osx to windows). I have to change the config.json files for all the machines so it works on another computer, because the path to the certs and machine are all hardcoded in the config file.

while this approach works, it's a bit tedious if we need to share them with everyone on the team. Is there a way to export or import the machine? or there are other ways to archive what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Until this feature gets implemented natively (see [Issue 23](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/23)), you can use this import/export script I've written.

https://gist.github.com/schickling/2c48da462a7def0a577e

#### Export (on host A)

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME       ACTIVE   DRIVER         STATE     URL                            SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
dev        -        digitalocean   Running   tcp://example.com:2376                 v1.10.1

$ ./docker-machine-export.sh dev
Exported machine to dev.zip

$ ls
docker-machine-import.sh
docker-machine-export.sh
dev.zip
```

#### Import (on host B)

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME       ACTIVE   DRIVER         STATE     URL                            SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS

$ ./docker-machine-import.sh dev.zip
Exported machine to dev.zip

$ docker-machine ls
NAME       ACTIVE   DRIVER         STATE     URL                            SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
dev        -        digitalocean   Running   tcp://example.com:2376                 v1.10.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, the *only* way is essentially what you've already done.

At some point in the nebulous future, there will be a "Machine Server" component that would securely store machine certs and allow teams to share access to machines. There's been *some* talk about this, but nothing formal has been started yet. There is a mention in [the roadmap](https://github.com/docker/machine/blob/master/ROADMAP.md).

Also perhaps worthy of note is [a proposal](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/773) for a machine declaration file which could be shared between people, which would allow people to create different machines with the same configuration (which isn't *quite* what you're looking for).

Answer (score 0):

As Dave mentioned, it's not possible today, but it's very much on our minds.

https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/2516 is how I've been proposing to solve this lately.  That would get everyone going in the right direction and allow sharing machine directories / `config.json` from computer to computer without doing custom modifications like you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway to get around the x509 certificate signed by unknown authority error?
I'm guessing since I created these machines on my laptop the certs were generated there and my cloud docker admin instance doesn't trust my certs.